# Java ArrayList.remove() problem

Tags: java

This is part of my code.

```
Integer keyLocation = reducedFD.indexOf(KeyPlus.get(KEYindex));
someArrayList.remove(keyLocation);
```

So what I am doing here is I assign keyLocation(the first occurence of a string in the reducedFD arrayList). But when I want to remove from someArrayList the item with that keyLocation, it will not work.

If I input manually:

```
someArrayList.remove(0); //Let's say 0 is the actual keyLocation
```

This actually works.

What is weird is THAT THE FOLLOWING CODE ALSO WORKS:

```
someArrayList.remove(keyLocation + 1);
```

Any hints?

Here is the main loop:

```
for (int KEYindex = 0; KEYindex < KeyPlus.size(); KEYindex++){

 Integer keyLocation = reducedFD.indexOf(KeyPlus.get(KEYindex));

if (reducedFD.contains(KeyPlus.get(KEYindex))){

 KeyPlus.add(reducedFD.get(keyLocation+1));
 CheckedAttributesPlus.add(KeyPlus.get(KEYindex));
 reducedFD.remove(keyLocation);

}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "it will not work"?  Computer reboots, I assume?

Comment: By "it will not work", I mean it does not remove it at all. It ignores it.

Comment: Can you put your code a bit more detailed? A little bit more code..

Comment: so how do you know it doesn't remove it?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The problem is you are passing an Integer to the remove method, and not an int. When you pass an Integer, it assumes that the Integer itself is what you are trying to remove, not the value at that index. Compare the methods

```
remove(Object o)
remove(int i)
```

so do:

```
int keyLocation = reducedFD.indexOf(KeyPlus.get(KEYindex));
someArrayList.remove(keyLocation);
```

Comment: I was stuck on this for more than an hour.. Thanks dude... :)

Comment: +1, for someone new to Java, the idea that `int` and `Integer` are different is kind of confusing. Thanks.

Comment: this was eaten my 2 hours.thanx

Comment: Oh boy, I spent 2 hours figuring out why my object doesn't get removed.....thanks

Answer (score 14):

Here is short description :

```
remove(Object o) // remove object
remove(int index) // remove the object in that index
```

if you write `.remove(5)` compiler understands it as a primitive type so as a **index** and remove `index(5).` If you want to remove object you should write `.remove(new Integer(5))`

Answer (score 3):

The `List` interface has two `remove()` methods, one that receives an `Object` (and tries to remove this object from the list) and another that receives an `int` (and tries to remove the object whose index is the given int).

Usually, giving a method an `Integer` parameter results in auto-unboxing, or automatic transform to a primitive `int`. In this case, the compiler will not attempt auto-unboxing, because there's a perfectly good method there that receives `Object`, and `Integer instanceof Object`... I'm guessing your list is not `List<Integer>`, which is why it fails spectacularly.

Adding an int to your `Integer` forces auto-unboxing, and the addition results in an `int` - perfect for the other `remove()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int keyLocation = reducedFD.indexOf(KeyPlus.get(KEYindex)); //Use a primitive int
    someArrayList.remove(keyLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just do:

```
 someArrayList.remove(keyLocation + 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this instead of creating an *int*

```
someArrayList.remove(integerKeyLocation.intValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `ArrayList` JavaDoc, you'll find this declaration.

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    public E remove(int index){
    .
    .
    .
}
```

`Integer` is different than `int`. Does the following make sense?

```
someArrayList.remove((int)keyLocation);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear let's understand with an example. Don't read again if you get confused on the first read!!

Think, this is the list (`<object>`) I have:

```
one
two
four
five
six
```

**int**

```
int x = 3;
remove(x);   //this will remove "five"
```

**Integer**

```
Integer x = 3;
remove(x);   //this will remove nothing
```

**String**

```
String x = "three"
remove(x);   //this will remove nothing (as "three" is not there)
```